# Soldering double deck pin headers

Tags: pcb, soldering, pins

Please take a look at a PCB like this one (STM32 Nucleo64 board):

[image]

They utilized so called "double deck" or "stacked" headers, meaning they can be used from both sized (top and bottom).

My question is- how does one solder them, since they come in such package:

[image]
Source: https://www.tme.eu/gb/details/zl2019-2x20/pin-headers/ninigi/zl2019-40/

I mean, you want the PCB to be in between the pin holding materials. It seems to me that one of them should be taken off after the initial soldering. The problem is that there is no good position for soldering without touching the holding bars:

[image]

Should the bards be altered by hand? That makes it easy for the pins to be soldered uneven... I just don't see it. I would appreciate all help regarding this topic.

Comment: Quite simply, the part you pictured is not right for this usage.   It might have the same length electrical contacts, but the wrong plastic/position.  With careful use of a vise and heat you might be able to move the plastic to adapt a few pieces, but it's not the part you are looking for.

Comment: Do you have any reference for the part I am looking for? I could not find anything better. Also, what is this one for then? I cannot picture any usage for it...

Comment: The one you found is presumably for permanently stacking two boards.

Comment: Makes sense, but its a bit weird that the lengths of the pins are different for both ends...

Answer (score 1):

The plastic pieces can be removed. Press gently and uniformly and extract one of the pieces. Then solder the whole and place the plastic piece back.

You can use a bit of heat or lubricant, but very carefully and in the latter be assured that it has been completely removed before soldering the pins.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I agree it is doable with this one and I will have to manage. Its just that like others said- it is not the connector I was looking for apparently.